# Injectivity of maps in a free product group with amalgamation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory, free-product

Given countable groups $H, G_1$ and $G_2$ and group homomorphisms $\theta_i: H \rightarrow
 G_i$, we can construct the free group with amalgamation $(G_1 \ast G_2)/N$ where $N$ is the normal subgroup generated by the elements $\theta_1(h) \theta_2(h^{-1})$ with $h \in H$.
We have canonical homomorphisms $\rho_i: G_i \rightarrow (G_1 \ast G_2)/N$.

 
My question is: if $\theta_1$ is injective, does it follow that $\rho_2$ is injective? References are welcome as well!

 
The question has its origin from category theory, where the amalgamated free product is the pushout. In some categories my question has a positive answer.

Comment: The answer is not categorical. There are varieties of groups where some amalgams cannot be even weakly embedded (e.g., nilpotent groups of class 2). so the argument has to rely on the explicit construction, which you can find in many textbooks.

Comment: This is not really my domain I'm too familiar with. What do you mean by "a group cannot be weakly embedded in another group"? How does my question relate to the amalgamated free product being embedded (weakly) in some other group? Thanks!

Comment: An amalgam of groups is a pushout diagram of groups $H\to G$, $H\to K$. where the maps are embeddings. You say the amalgam is weakly embeddable if there is a group $M$ and embeddings $G,K\to M$ such that the intersection of the images of $G$ and $K$ contains $H$. It is strongly embeddable if the intersection of the images is *exactly* $H$. There are examples of nilpotent groups of class $2$ (one can say the closest thing to abelian groups you can have without abelianness) $G$ and $K$, and a common subgroup $H$, but no nil-2 group $M$ into which you can embed the amalgam.

Comment: A proof that the constitutent maps $\phi_i$ are embeddings when both $\theta_i$ are embeddings can be found in Rotman's *Introduction to the Theory of groups", 4th Edition, Theorem 11.67.

Comment: Thanks, it's nice to know it holds when both maps are embeddings! 
In regard to your first and second comment: is your point that in the category of nilpotent groups of class 2, the pushout does not exist? 
If so, that's no issue, since I'm working in the category of countable groups.

Comment: The category of nilpotent groups of class 2 is a variety, so it is in fact a reflective subcategory of $\mathsf{Group}$. As such, pushout exists, as do coproducts, etc. But in this category, you can have a pushout where both $\theta_i$ are embeddings, but  neither of the $\rho_j$ are embeddings. This means that whether $\rho_2$ is an embedding or not in a particular category will not be a categorical question, but rather will depend on the specific category and the specific constructions at issue.